# Is it possible to use column names with spaces in NamedAgg expressions?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Is it possible to create names with spaces and special characters when naming an aggregation column using `pandas.NamedAgg` aggregation function? The typical syntax would be:

```
pvt = (df.groupby(by=[....])
         .agg(value=pd.NamedAgg(column='col', aggfunc='count'))
      )
```

But is there a way to create a column name that is not a valid python variable name (as `value` in this example), but something like `'my new column name'`?

The only solution that I can think of now is to rename `value` afterwards:

```
.rename(columns={'value': 'my new column name'})
```

Comment: I think not yet.

Comment: a possible way to go ahead would be to introduce a syntax using dictionaries: `.agg({'my new column name': pd.NamedAgg(column='col', aggfunc='count)})`. But I am sure the pandas guys are already thinking of this.

Comment: They likely didn't support that syntax because Python already has a solution: dictionary unpacking

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your column name does not make a valid Python variable name, you can use dictionary unpacking:

```
df.groupby(...).agg(**{
    'My New Column Name': ('col_name', 'mean'),
    'Column 42@#$': ('col_name', 'max')
})
```

Comment: Oh, that's beautiful, I was not aware o fthis!

Comment: Super cool! Is there a way to do it with a lambda function or user-defined function?